# PayPal doesn't work in sandbox and return 400 error code

Tags: ios, paypal-sandbox

I have some problems with PayPal on iOS.

I created my app at https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps

I set `App Return URL(test)`,`App Return URL(live)` to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout-mobile&token=valueFromSetExpressCheckoutResponse

I created some **test-account** at https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts (and it is not the same with my email what I register before)

And next, I used sample app at https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK with my Client-ID (I get my client-id at https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps)

I run PayPal SDK demo,

- set environment to Sandbox (not Mock, not live),
- touch on "Buy T-shirt",
- login with my **test-account** I've created (OK, it successes)

But when I touch on "Send Payment", it didn't work. I got error code **400**.

**I think there are some problem with `App Return URL` but I dont know why :(((**

```
2014-04-01 09:53:58.564 PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App[793:907] PayPal iOS SDK version: PayPal iOS SDK 2.0.1
2014-04-01 09:54:00.675 PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App[793:907] Environment: mock. Accept credit cards? 0
2014-04-01 09:54:01.758 PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App[793:907] Environment: sandbox. Accept credit cards? 0
2014-04-01 09:54:17.454 PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App[793:907] PayPal SDK: Request has failed with error: VALIDATION_ERROR - The payment information is invalid. Please correct and submit again. (400) | PayPal Debug-ID: d1ebd2436f0b9 | Details: (
        {
        field = "redirect_urls";
        issue = "This field required when payment_method is 'paypal'";
    }
).
```

**Question:**

I try many ways else but not work! Someone help me!!!

I found that I can create app at https://apps.paypal.com/user/my-account/applications too. But if I create my app here, I received an other client-id (its format is not the same with clien-id what I create at https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps)

Answer (score 0):

OK! I solved my problem

My old test account has email like `********-facilitator@*****.com` and it **balance is ZERO**

I've created new test-acount with balance is 9999$ and payment is OK :D

But I don't know why `PayPal` returned that error. It doesn't relate with this reason

[image]